# What is the name of this Monad Stack function?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, state-monad

I've got a bunch of stateful functions inside a State monad. At one point in the program there needs to be some IO actions so I've wrapped IO inside a StateT getting a pair of types like this:

```
mostfunctions :: State Sometype a
toplevel :: StateT Sometype IO a
```

To keep things simple I don't want pass the IO context into the main set of functions and I would like to avoid wrapping them in the monad stack type. But in order to call them from the toplevel function I need something akin to a lift, but I'm not trying to lift a value from the inner monad. Rather I want to convert the state in the StateT monad into something equivalent in the State monad. To do this I've got the following:

```
wrapST :: (State Sometype a) -> StateT Sometype IO a
wrapST f = do s <- get
              let (r,s2) = runState f s 
              put s2
              return r
```

This then get used to interleave things like the following:

```
toplevel = do liftIO $ Some IO functions
              wrapST $ Some state mutations
              liftIO $ More IO functions
              ....
```

It seems like a fairly obvious block of code so I'm wondering does this function have a standard name, and it is already implemented somewhere in the standard libraries? I've tried to keep the description simple but obviously this extends to pulling one transformer out of a stack, converting the wrapped value to the cousin of the transformer type, skipping the monads below in the stack, and then pushing the results back in at the end.

Comment: Can't you use the fact, that `type State = StateT Identity`? Use `StateT Sometype m a` for the big bunch of functions, so you can run them in both `StateT IO` and `State`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It may be a good idea to refactor your code to use the type `StateT SomeType m a` instead of `State SomeType a`, because the first one is compatible to an arbitrary monad stack. If you'd change it like this, you don't need a function `wrapST` anymore, since you can call the stateful functions directly.

Okay. Suppose you have a function `subOne :: Monad m => State Int Int`:

```
subOne = do a <- get
            put $ a - 1
            return a
```

Now, change the types of all functions like this one from `State SomeType a` to `StateT SomeType m a`, leaving `m` as is. This way, your functions can work on any monadic stack. For those functions, that require IO, you can specify, that the monad at the bottom must be IO:

```
printState :: MonadIO m => StateT Int m ()
printState = do a <- get
             liftIO $ print a
```

Now, it should be possible to use both functions together:

```
-- You could use me without IO as well!
subOne :: Monad m => StateT Int m ()
subOne = do a <- get
            put $ a - 1

printState :: MonadIO m => StateT Int m ()
printState = do a <- get
             liftIO $ print a

toZero :: StateT Int IO ()
toZero = do subOne     -- A really pure function
            printState -- function may perform IO
            a <- get
            when (a > 0) toZero
```

PS: I use GHC 7, some of the libs changed midway, so it might be a bit different on GHC 6.

Comment: It doesn't work when I try it "Couldn't match expected type Identity againsted Inferred type IO". I can't fit a code fragment in these comments, could you post a simple example of what you mean?

Comment: Excellent, that's a much simpler way of achieving what I was looking for. And it answers my original question as well: that the function that I was looking for is a standard part of a transformer. btw the signature for subOne needs a "Monad m =>" added for ghci.

Comment: For `printState` and `toZero`, it might be good to allow any monad, as long as IO is at the bottom of the stack, i.e. `printState :: MonadIO m => StateT Int m ()`, or just remove the type signature :)

Comment: @hammar: Ah... forgot about that.

Comment: Side note: In the latest Haskell Platform, State is defined in terms of StateT, and the same is true of all monads which can be generalised to monad transformers, I think. Until very recently, this was not the case. This doesn't change the correctness of the answer: StateT should still be used because it's more general.

Answer (score 3):

A more direct answer to your question: the function `hoist` does exactly what you're describing in a slightly more generic way. Example usage:

```
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Functor.Identity
import Control.Monad.Morph

foo :: State Int Integer
foo = put 1 >> return 1

bar :: StateT Int IO Integer
bar = hoist (return . runIdentity) foo
```

`hoist` is part of the `MFunctor` class, which is defined like this:

```
class MFunctor t where
  hoist :: Monad m => (forall a. m a -> n a) -> t m b -> t n b
```

There are instances for most monad tranformers, but not `ContT`.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually the answer I was originally looking for.